How to increase timeout in RestAssued? Getting Connection reset by peer: socket write error
I have a web service with a file upload feature. Since we had issues uploading bigger files (8 mb and bigger) we wanted to have automated tests for it.
For some reason the upload fails and as far as I can tell it happens on RestAssureds side. The web service receives the request but the request is closed before anything can happen. It works with our internal API which also uses Java.
In my RestAssured test I get the following error: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
To my knowledge that is usually caused by the server but why would our API work? The backend is written in Go using Gin, if that matters. We have a middleware that logs all incoming requests, that is what I see. After that the function linked to that route is not called at all.
The test looks like this:
@Test
@Timeout(value = 2, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public void upload8MbFile() throws Exception {
    String fileName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
    String url = String.format(PATH, fileName + ".txt");
    int size = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
    File file = createTempFile(fileName, size);

    RestAssured
            .given()
            .log().all()
            .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
            .auth()
            .basic(Config.adminUser, Config.adminPassword)
            .body(file)
            .when()
            .put(url)
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200);
}

I also tried to set the timeout on different ways I found online:
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    // Does not do anything
    RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config()
            .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                    .setParam("http.socket.timeout", 10000)
                    .setParam("http.connection.timeout", 10000));

    // Results in different errors
    RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config()
            .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                    .setParam("http.connection.timeout", 180000)
                    .setParam("http.connection.request.timeout", 180000)
                    .setParam("http.connection-manager.timeout", 180000));

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                                                .setConnectTimeout(50000)
                                                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(50000)
                                                .setSocketTimeout(50000)
                                                .build();
    HttpClientConfig httpClientFactory = HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
            .httpClientFactory(() -> HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build());
    RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientFactory);
}

The test that does work is my manual test with HttpBuilder:
@Test
public void upload8MbFileAlt() throws Exception {
    String fileName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
    String url = String.format(PATH, fileName + ".txt");
    int size = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
    File file = createTempFile(fileName, size);

    URI uri = new URI(url);
    HttpClient client = getNewClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                     .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((Config.adminUser + ":" + Config.adminPassword).getBytes()))
                                     .method("PUT", BodyPublishers.ofFile(file.toPath()))
                                     .uri(uri)
                                     .build();
    BodyHandler<byte[]> bodyHandler = BodyHandlers.ofByteArray();
    HttpResponse<byte[]> response = client.send(request, bodyHandler);

    assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
}

private HttpClient getNewClient() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        X509TrustManager nvtm = new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
            
        };
        sslcontext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { nvtm }, null);

        Builder builder = HttpClient.newBuilder().executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(500));
        builder.sslContext(sslcontext);
        return builder.build();
}

So, what is going on with RestAssured?

what if you try to send 1 kb file to the server?

@AlexeyR. it works for smaller files, my test for 260 kb works fine. Let me test a bit to find the limit.

I tested it: 3.8, 3.9 mb work, 4 mb does not work. So the limit is somewhere between 3.9 and 4.0 mb.

I noticed that you have log().all(). Is there any valuable clue in the log?

@AlexeyR. no, nothing. I added it to get more info but there is none. Only the exception.
